# ReaderWriterLockSlim - Not sure how this works

Tags: c#, .net, locking

I have the following declared on a Singleton type object named CicApplication:

```
internal static List<Fcda> FcdaCache
{
   get
   {
      // If the current thread already has a write lock, no need to attempt to acquire a read lock (which would fail anyway)
      if (CoaterDataLock.IsWriteLockHeld)
         return _fcdaCache;

      CoaterDataLock.EnterReadLock();
      try
      {
         return _fcdaCache;
      }
      finally
      {
         CoaterDataLock.ExitReadLock();
      }
   }
}
```

'CoaterDataLock' is declared as ReaderWriterLockSlim object

Elsewhere in my code, I perform the following query on 'FcdaCache':

```
CicApplication.FcdaCache.Where(row => row.Coater == coater)
```

My question is this. When I perform this query, will an attempt be made to get a read lock on FcdaCache? I assume it will but was not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your code doesn't lock anything. You enter the lock, return the `_fcdaCache` and leave the lock. **After** that you make a `.Where(...)` on that cache, which is then **unlocked**, so concurrency exceptions may occur or data races may happen.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think you're right and I need to look into this further.